# GAE images.resize with fixed proportional crop

Tags: google-app-engine, image, image-resizing

I need to resize and crop to exactly 60x80px from various size and
aspect ratio. Just before i put into Datastore. Anyone already got
this issue resolved.

Currently i already succed to just transform it to exact height (80px)
with various width which nott look so good when i try to display it on
a list. e.g jcaroussel.

My db.put code is like bellow:

```
    if users.get_current_user():
        personal.personal_id = int(self.request.get('personal_id'))
        personal.name = self.request.get('name')
        personal.latitude = self.request.get('latitude')
        personal.info = self.request.get('info')
        photo = images.resize(self.request.get('img'), 0, 80)
        personal.photo = db.Blob(photo)
        personal.lc_id = int(self.request.get('lc_id'))
        personal.put()
        self.redirect('/admin/personal')

    else:
      self.response.out.write('I\'m sorry, you don\'t have permission to add this LP Personal Data.')
```

I just want to do similar result when we upload our avatar on google
talk/google chat.

Anyone solved this?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something else:

- Resize the original image to your max height (80)
- Store the resized (but complete/not cropped) image
- Display it inside a `<div>` that has the following CSS: `width: 60px; height: 80px; overflow: hidden;`

That way it will show nicely in your list, but you can still display the complete resized picture on your user's profile page (looking at you code I imagine that's what you are trying to do, right?)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want ... 
But, i have problem to implement the css hack since i use jcarousel - http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ to display those images ...

Thx  Emilien

Answer (score 1):

After your resize your image down to 80 pixels in height, you would have to use the `crop` function as defined [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass.html#Image_crop). For example:

```
img = images.Image(self.request.get('img'))
img.resize(0, 80)
resized_img = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
left_x = (resized_img.width - 60) / 2
resized_img.crop(left_x, 0, left_x + 60, 80)
cropped_img = resized_image.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)
```

In my example it crops to the center of the image.
It assumes that the resized image is at least 60 pixels wide, but obviously you would have to add some checks to confirm this, because a user might not upload an image in the right size.

Comment: @user288541: I realized there was a mistake in my code sample. See the updated sample above (added execute_transforms call).

Comment: left_x = (resized_img.width - 60) / 2
--> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'width'
Should i use some other import module to fix this?
Thx for kind help Tom

Comment: @Ivan: I realized that images.resize returns the image data as a string, not an Image object. I have updated the sample above to use an Image object created from the initial image data.

Comment: My result is just the same as my first script does. proportional for 80px height but doesn't crop width to 60px.... 
:-) Thx for help Tom ... maybe we have to request feature for google images ....

Comment: @Ivan: it is definitely supported in the images API. The crop function should crop the image to the required size. I have used this function myself in some code in the past. Could you please append the code you tried in your question? Maybe there is a typo of some sorts.